# 5.4.0-77-generic module e1000e complains about hardware error

Tags: 20.04, kernel, lubuntu

yesterday I updatet my lubuntu 20.04 that shipps a new kernel. I bootete it today up and get

```
dmesg | grep -i hard
[    0.040601] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    7.514435] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): Hardware Error
[   10.261171] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
[   14.944977] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Hardware Error
```

So I search in dmesg for previous boot with linux-image-5.4.0-74-generic

```
grep -i hard /var/log/dmesg.0
[    0.039776] kernel: Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    4.091866] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
```

relevant hardware detail

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 00:21:cc:ce:85:21
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:29 memory:f2500000-f251ffff memory:f253b000-f253bfff ioport:5080(size=32)
```

I found bootoption

```
pcie_aspm=off
```

But would this not deactivate Active State Power Management for all pci devices? Or I'm wrong?  I take a look in

```
modinfo e1000e | fgrep parm
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
parm:           copybreak:Maximum size of packet that is copied to a new buffer on receive (uint)
parm:           TxIntDelay:Transmit Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           TxAbsIntDelay:Transmit Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxIntDelay:Receive Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxAbsIntDelay:Receive Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Interrupt Throttling Rate (array of int)
parm:           IntMode:Interrupt Mode (array of int)
parm:           SmartPowerDownEnable:Enable PHY smart power down (array of int)
parm:           KumeranLockLoss:Enable Kumeran lock loss workaround (array of int)
parm:           WriteProtectNVM:Write-protect NVM [WARNING: disabling this can lead to corrupted NVM] (array of int)
parm:           CrcStripping:Enable CRC Stripping, disable if your BMC needs the CRC (array of int)
```

Is there a possibility to deactivate power management for my ethercard there?

Note I have no idea if the card is in this state works (no router here).                        .

Answer (score 0):

Please try booting the kernel with the pcie_aspm=off kernel parameter.

Comment: OP tried that already